# How can I create curved lines between blocks?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

**My problem and trying to fix it:** I can't draw curved lines between blocks in the parent container. I have tried to generate lines between blocks, so:

- I started on user hold to generate a strip under which the canvas is generated, so roughly speaking, the canvas is over the parent container and its beginning and end connects the two blocks

```java
@Composable
fun DrawingScreen() {
 var path by remember { mutableStateOf(Path()) }
 var lineThickness by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
 var canvasSize by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
 var isDrawing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

 Box(
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
 ) {
     Box(
         modifier = Modifier
             .fillMaxWidth()
             .height(100.dp)
             .background(Color.White)
             .pointerInput(Unit) {
                 detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                     val x = change.position.x
                     val y = change.position.y
                     if (change.pressure > 0.1f) {
                         path.lineTo(x, y)
                         lineThickness = change.pressure * 30
                         if (!isDrawing) {
                             isDrawing = true
                             canvasSize = 0
                         }
                     } else {
                         path.moveTo(x, y)
                     }
                     canvasSize = max(canvasSize, path.getBounds().width.toInt())
                 }
             }
     )
     if (isDrawing) {
         Canvas(
             modifier = Modifier
                 .size(canvasSize.dp, canvasSize.dp)
                 .offset(y = 100.dp)
         ) {
             drawPath(
                 path = path,
                 color = Color.Black,
                 alpha = 1f,
                 style = Stroke(width = lineThickness)
             )
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Perhaps you will say that this is some kind of perversion? I completely agree with you, but I do not really understand what other approach can be applied, the reference was taken from Blueprint (screenshot attached below).*

[image]

> **Problem:** unfortunately, I can't generate a Canvas for the arrow. Can you tell me, maybe I approached this task incorrectly or maybe there is a ready-made api to work with this kind of stuff?
> I also managed to find a library which might be able to help me, but unfortunately it is only written for SwiftUI
> https://github.com/Bersaelor/SwiftSplines
> Maybe you know an analogue for Jetpack Compose?